# How to send an AJAX call to server

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a question related to AJAX. I am implementing AJAX, and it's implemented successfully, but I am stuck at this point.

When user clicks on a specific image, I want a request to be sent to the server, and the server should return the image. I know how the server will return the image, but don't know what the key should be that will be send to the server for the server to recognize the specific image request. Here is the code for the front end:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost:3306","root","root");
if (!$con)
  {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  else
      {
            mysql_select_db("uploading", $con);
            $sql_get=mysql_query("select * from imge");
            while ($db_field=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_get))
                {
                    $img_urls=$db_field["link"];
                    ?>
                <img onclick="ajaxFunction()" id="<?  echo $img_urls; ?>" src="<?php echo $img_urls; ?>" style="width: 200px;height: 200px;border-style: solid;border-color: blue"/>
<!--            <a href="view.php?next=<?php echo $img_urls; ?>">View</a>-->

<?php
          }
      }
?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ajaxFunction()
            {
                var xmlHttp;
                try {   // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
                    xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                } catch (e ) { // Internet Explorer
                    try {
                        xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    catch (e) {
                        try {
                            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        } catch (e) {
                            alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }

                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
                    {
                        document.getElementById("div").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText

                    }
                }

                xmlHttp.open("GET","server_image.php?url=<?php echo $img_urls ?>",true);
                xmlHttp.send(null);
            }
</script>
                <p id="div"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic "smells like Ajax but isn't" problem. What you want to do is simply change the src attibute of the image to something that will return the image data.

Comment: but in response i have to show the image, and when user clicks on the image, request of the clicked image should be send to server and in return server should returns the image_url

Comment: If the image is displaying in the browser, you already have the URL to the image. Just alert this.src in your onclick handler.

Comment: the images are loaded once when user clicks on the view link, they are not loaded through the Ajax call